# How to verify data meets certain condition before inserting into database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am currently developing an invoicing system.
I would like to insert multiple invoice items into database, before inserting these items, I would like to verify that all items are already added into items table.
Currently, the code alerts the user that the item does exist but still insert the data:

My jquery code:

```js
var query = $('#item_name'+no).val(); 
  $.ajax({ 
  url:"ajax.php", 
  method:"POST", 
  data:{query:query}, 
  success:function(data) { 
    result = data; if (result == 0) { 
     alert("Please make sure that you use existing item"); 
     $('#item_name'+no).focus(); return false; 
   } 
  } 
 });
```

If I change the code to the following, when an item does not exist, it alerts and prevent from inserting, but if everything is correct, it only prevents from inserting.

```js
var query = $('#item_name' + no).val();
$.ajax({
  url: "ajax.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    query: query
  },
  success: function(data) {
    result = data;
    if (result == 0) {
      alert("Please make sure that you use existing item");
      $('#item_name' + no).focus();
    }
  }
});
return false;
}
```

I think I would work if I could send the data outside ajax.

My php page:

Thank you for your help

Comment: Sounds like you need to do this on the `php` end (before inserting into `db`). `Ajax` allows you to send the data, what you do with it once received is up to you.

Comment: Validation should be perform at the front-end and at the back-end for security purposes. In the front-end, you could use a jQuery plugin such as jquery.validate.js to make your life easier. Then, I would advice to see if you can find some PHP library that is reliable. Some of this form validation plugin in jQuery allows you send the information back to the server to validate prior to submit so you only need one place where to set the validation rules (the back-end).

Answer (score 0):

First , please edit your code, because it's hard to understand it.

I would just simply use 'if' condition, and than run ajax. If conditions are not meet just throw an error or something. I don't know what condition data should meet but maybe you can use for loop to check each cell with maybe [regular expressions](https://regexr.com/)

I don't know if i understood your problem so please comment if you need anything else.

Hope it will help.